# `JS: Error: Css styling failed: missing '{'` in nativescript-dev-sass plugin

Tags: css, sass, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

After installing the nativescript-dev-sass plugin, I renamed the `app.css` file in my /app directory to `app.scss` so that I could write sass in the file. The css file contained one import statement, so I changed it from:

```
@import 'nativescript-theme-core/css/sky.css';
```

to

```
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/css/sky.css'; //notice the tilde
```

I am using the tilde as mentioned in the readme of the nativescript-dev-sass repository here: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-sass

When I run `tns run android` I get the following error when my app starts:

```
JS: Error: Css styling failed: Error: /data/data/io.myapp.app/files/app/app.css:1:97: missing '{'
```

The resulting `app.css` file that is compiled from `app.scss` has the below line:

```
@import url(C:\my_workspace\myapp\node_modules\nativescript-theme-core\css\sky.css)
```

Column 97 of that line, as specified in the error message, is the one right after the closing parenthesis ), and there really shouldn't be a { there. So I have no idea why it's saying the the { is missing.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you need to use

```
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/scss/sky';  // #theme variables
```

instead of

```
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/css/sky.css'; //notice the tilde
```